# FME - Possible to return a value from workspace?

Tags: coordinate-system, fme-form

I'm calling my workspace from the command line (either via Python or .NET to a system/os call). I'm parsing DWGs and pushing attributes to SQL Server in the workspace. Either the data validates in the workspace or it doesn't. I need to return a value of 'pass/fail' to my calling application from my workspace based on whether or not the data validated within the workspace. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the exit code from the program; eg echo %errorlevel%

If it is 0 then the workspace ran successfully.

In the workspace, when you locate bad data then terminate the translation with a Terminator transformer. That should change the exit code to be non-zero.

Hence a non-zero errorlevel denotes bad data.

**NB** Read this first on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line)

Other methods to get that information out would be to write it to a file with the Textline writer, or an AttributeFileWriter transformer. Then you could write your own exit code according to the type of problem.

Yet another method might be to utilize a [Python shutdown script](http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/Startup_and_Shutdown_Scripts) in some way.

I think it really depends on what you plan to do with the pass/fail information, and how.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I think I'm going to (try to) create parameters to get the values I need returned, then use a Python shutdown script to get them and return them somehow. I might also try the AttributeFileWriter to keep track of some things along the way.

Answer (score 2):

If you want more than a simple workspace pass/fail you could also parse the resulting FME log file.  You can control the logfile location with the LOG_FILENAME command line option as described at http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/FAQ/Batch-Processing-Method-2-Command-File#heading_toc_j_3 (LOG_FILENAME is not just for batch processing).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use either

http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/XQueryExtractor

or

http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/Data_Validation_with_FME_Server

or both.

Comment: I'm using FME Desktop (should have noted that earlier). I don't really see how either of these can do what I need, honestly.

Comment: I have seen the capability to call values within a workspace from published parameters from another workspace. Are you trying to utilize values in a completely different application?